# How to make a radio selected field determine the next page when submitt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hello i'm near at the end of my multi step form , so all and good
i have validate my form with php and javascript but what i need now is when a user click
one of the radios inside my form that radio value to determine the destination of the user after submitting my form.

To make it more clear i want when a user chek one of my three radio inputs the checked input radio to bring him in the desired page after submitting the form in my case the desired chekoutpage.
hear my radio code :

```
                      <div id="emotion" name="emotion1" >
                          <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="basi" value="Basic Pack"   />
                          <label for="basi"><img src="images/basi.jpg" width="630px" alt="basi"  /></label><br>

                          <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="deli"  value="Deluxe Pack" />
                          <label for="deli"><img src="images/deli.jpg" width="630px" alt="deli" /></label><br>

                         <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="premi"  value="Premium Pack"/>
                         <label for="premi"><img src="images/premi.jpg" width="630px" alt="premi" /></label>
                      </div><hr>
```

and in php i have this code that bring the user back in the form after submitting the echo tag :

```
    if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
        {
            mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
        } } 

    echo "<script>
                 alert('message sent succesfully'); 
                 window.history.go(-1);
         </script>";

    }

?>
```

To make it even more clearer i want eg radio1 radio2 radio3 if radio1 selcted than after submit html5
if radio2 than after submit html6  i hope i was clear 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You would use a conditional statement to check the value of the radio button and then deliver the redirect using `header("http://domain.tld/ext");`..etc

Comment: can you elaborate this a bit more i don't understand exactly what you mean. thanks

Comment: You don't have a named form element called `copy`, so why include it in your code/question? Do you have one but didn't include it in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what Ohgodwhy was referring to is make a condition/redirection based on what the user input is:

```
$emotion = $_POST['emotion'];

if($emotion == 'Basic Pack') {
    header('Location: html5.php');
} elseif($emotion == 'Deluxe Pack') {
    header('Location: html6.php');
} elseif($emotion == 'Premium Pack') {
    header('Location: html7.php');
}
// or by using switch() which ever you're comfortable with
```

Sidenote: By the way, you can't use that `alert()` with the PHP header redirect. Because an output has already took place.

If you wan't to preserve that `alert()`, might as well use javascript redirect all the way through.

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Comment: OP's values are `value="Basic Pack"` - `value="Deluxe Pack"` - `value="Premium Pack"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah my hand where to lazy to scroll more and eyes where so lazy to look closely, thanks for the heads up

Comment: so you guys mean that i should redirect the user again after submitting in the form page and than jquery script to active and send the user to the desired html or how ?

Comment: @NewLogo no, this code fragment must be used on the same php file that processed the form. put it there when the `action="php.php"` file is pointed to

Comment: you mean like this :  <form id="sky-form"  class="sky-form" name="newlogo" method="post" action="action.php <script $emotion = $_POST['emotion'];

if($emotion == 'Basic Pack') {
    header('Location: html5.php');
} elseif($emotion == 'Deluxe Pack') {
    header('Location: html6.php');
} elseif($emotion == 'Premium Pack') {
    header('Location: html7.php');
}</script>">

Comment: sory guys but im little confused and tired here in eu its 06 morning

Comment: @NewLogo no what i mean is, this code goes inside your php, you're still coding from night till morning? thats not good for your health! :p you need some rest

Comment: haha we have a to launch our web in the coming days and we need this immediately to test things up so yeah when needed we must haha besides i'll try this yet with the hope it works and buy me my ticket to bed :p

Comment: @NewLogo haha okay, anyway, the code i provided is for the php form process, i hope it turns out well

Comment: thank you guys its working as i wanted , have an awesome napp all over the world people cuz yet it's my time :P